# Webapi CORS request with browsers returning JSON but with phonegap it returns HTML

Tags: android, json, asp.net-web-api, phonegap-build

Webapi CORS request(www.abc.com/webapi/Getxyz) works fine with browsers and android emulators which is returning JSON but after building the application with phonegap build and installing on android device it returns HTML of a website on which it is hosted(**https**://www.abc.com).

The URL is HTTPS and I have made the necessary changes in config.xml file of phonegap application.like(access origin="*" ,access origin="https://*" )

But still it is giving me an error.
Is it required to make any changes at server side???
I need help ...

Comment: There might be some issue with content-type. Can you please share what error you are getting?

Comment: HERE IS MY CODE: function GetSomething() { 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: Url,
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {                    
                    info = JSON.stringify(data);
                },
                error: function (jqX, Status, errThr) {
                    alert("get err:" + jqX + '\n' + Status + '\n' + errThr);
                }
            });
        }

Comment: when the dataType: "json", this returns JSON which is working fine with browser....But this is giving me error in phonegap app. err::"unexpected token < "....and this is bcoz the server is returning HTML instead of JSON ...I checked this by changing the  dataType: "HTML" in Ajax call.There is no proper JSON and it will give the above error when it will try to parse HTML.

Comment: It is solved....Actually the server was redirecting to www.abc.com when it detects the device as a mobile...